# best way to extract column from line in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, performance

I wrote 3 different functions to fulfill one job, extracting a column from a line with some questionable format. I want to know which one is the fastest, how can I bench this variants in bash to get some performance data? And is it possible to somehow replace the two parameter substitution in function 2 to just one nested one, or with extglob enabled and {var//some_ext_glob} "search and replace"? And is there even a better variant than these three?

I just need to extract the second number in `$nasty_line` with `..` as suffix (ie, `1719914` in the following sample `$nasty_line`). space count differ in every line

```
#!/bin/bash

nasty_line='   574:        443..  694914:    1719914..   1815133: 194912:'


variant_one() {
  out=$1

  [[ ${out} =~ [[:digit:]]{7}\.{2} ]]

  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]%%.*}"
}

variant_two() {
  out=$1

  out=${out%..*}
  out=${out##*[[:blank:]]}

  echo "${out}"
}

variant_three() {
  out=$(tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' <<< "$1" | cut -f 5 -d ' ' | tr -d '.')

  echo "${out}"
}

variant_one "${nasty_line}"
variant_two "${nasty_line}"
variant_three "${nasty_line}"
```

Comment: [Worthwhile reading](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: small saving from eliminating `out=$1` and reference `$1` directly in the next command (as was done in variant 3)

Answer (score 2):

Added a fourth variant so you can compare. Anyway it is easy to see how the multiple subshell forking pipes get variant3 like 20 or 30 folds slower:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nasty_line='   574:        443..  694914:    1719914..   1815133: 194912:'

variant_one() {
  out=$1

  [[ ${out} =~ [[:digit:]]{7}\.{2} ]]

  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]%%.*}"
}

variant_two() {
  out=$1

  out=${out%..*}
  out=${out##*[[:blank:]]}

  echo "${out}"
}

variant_three() {
  out=$(tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' <<< "$1" | cut -f 5 -d ' ' | tr -d '.')

  echo "${out}"
}

variant_four() {
  IFS=' :.' read -r _ _ _ _ out _ <<< "$1"
  echo "$out"
}

variant_one "${nasty_line}"
variant_two "${nasty_line}"
variant_three "${nasty_line}"
variant_four "${nasty_line}"

for variant in variant_one variant_two variant_three variant_four; do
  printf 'Timings for: %s\n' "$variant"
  time for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do
    "$variant" "${nasty_line}" >/dev/null
  done
  echo
done
```

Output measured on my system:

```
1719914
1719914
1719914
1719914
Timings for: variant_one

real    0m0,952s
user    0m0,865s
sys 0m0,085s

Timings for: variant_two

real    0m1,917s
user    0m1,867s
sys 0m0,048s

Timings for: variant_three

real    0m20,087s
user    0m31,667s
sys 0m8,988s

Timings for: variant_four

real    0m1,569s
user    0m0,647s
sys 0m0,913s
```

Answer (score 1):

A modification to `variant_one` that:

- eliminates the `out=$1` (some reduction in timings)
- uses capture groups to separate the number from the `..` suffix (some increase in timings)

  variant_one_x() {

  ```
  [[ "${1}" =~ ([[:digit:]]{4,})(\.{2}) ]]     # '{4,}' and '{7}' don't seem to make a noticeable difference in speed

  #typeset -p BASH_REMATCH

  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  ```

  }

Uncommenting the `typeset -p` shows:

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="1719914.." [1]="1719914" [2]="..")
```

And of course the `echo ...` generates:

```
1719914
```

Léa's timer routine shows this is about 10-12% slower than the original `variant_one`.